# HoverItem returing null in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

During writing a custom control for listview: I am overriding this method like this:

```
protected override void OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
{
    base.OnDragDrop(drgevent);

    // get the currently hovered row that the items will be dragged to
    Point clientPoint = base.PointToClient(new Point(drgevent.X, drgevent.Y));
    ListViewItem hoverItem = base.GetItemAt(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);
```

Sometimes hoverItem becomes null :( It becomes null when I am dropping the item at the far right area of the listview...If I drop it somewhere in the list that there are items and text in there, it works fine, if I drop it at somewhere that items don't have text, then it becomes null.... 
[image]

I am attaching a picture for more clarity

What is the problem? or do you think there are better ways for doing this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are overriding `OnDragDrop`, instead of adding another event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem. This is by design. There is no item where the red dot is. ListView has different view modes (View property) where there can be icon/text "blocks" that enclose each item, or there can be multiple columns of items.

I think that setting the View property to View.Details and setting FullRowSelect to true, GetItemAt will hit on the whitespace to the end for each row, but I'd have to try it to be sure.

Comment: yeah I am looking for a way to make it return the item even if it is in the white area AND also I just need some view that looks like items of a ListBox ( each item in one line )

Comment: Did you try `Details` and `FullRowSelect`?

Comment: Worked!... I had Details from before...but I think FullRowSelect did the trick...thanks